# non-blocking socket client connection

Tags: linux, timeout, nonblocking, winsock2, qnx

ALL,
I am looking for a simple example of non-blocking socket connection that will run on Windows.
I tried to Google, but all samples are either for *nix (POSIX) or blocking sockets on Windows.

Looking thru msdn I see that it is easy to make a socket non-blocking and issue a connect(), but then you need some preparation in order to put the socket back.

So, all in all I need something on a non-blocking socket that will connect and then put it back to be blocking.
The read and write operation should be performed on the blocking socket.

The reason for a non-blocking socket is that I need a connection timeout and there is no other way than non-blocking socket. Or is there?

Thank you.

Comment: That's not the only way. You could also run the `connect` operation in another thread. Then you can wait or not wait for it however you like for as long as you like.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Good solution, but not for me. ;-) I am trying to connect for different devices at the same time each of which will be on its own thread. If I will spawn a thread just for connecting whoever will look at the code after me will be lost. And I might be lost myself. Besides the project target OS is Linux (maybe even QNX - real-time). Winidows will be just for demo. Thank you.

Comment: If the connections are going to be on their own thread anyway, why not have that thread just do the connection operation as well?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, What do you mean? Can you put some code please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ACE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Communication_Environment) [socket wrapper facade](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/wrapper-facade.pdf) and apply your Linux knowledge in full.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I prefer to use native solution without any additional libraries. Besides it might not have compatible license.

Comment: @Igor - just download it and see how it wraps socket IO on Windows, do not necessarily use it